# Return EOF from SCANF

Tags: c, scanf, eof

I still not understand how `scanf` return `EOF` value. The program running in window.

From the `scanf` description:

> "The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure."

code is

```
int main()
{
int status,a1,a2,b1;
char str1[100];

b1=EOF;
printf("b1=%d\n",b1);
printf("Enter input\n");
status=scanf("%d%d",&a1,&a2);
printf("status=%d",status);

return 0;
}
```

case1
input :

```
hello
```

output

```
status=0
```

case2
input :

```
^z  (press CTRL-Z)
```

output

```
staus=-1
```

In case 1 is the input failure  before the first conversion? if it is the input failure  before the first conversion
why scanf return 0.

In case 2 I press CTRL- Z to first input and scanf return -1
so the only way scanf return EOF is by press CTRL-Z?If not please explain me with example code

Comment: "Input failure" is not the same as "failed to parse the input". "Input failure" is things like end of file or an actual error reading.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` logic is rather simple. It returns:

- `EOF` if not a single character could be read from the stream at all.
- `EOF` if only leading white-space characters until an error or end-of-file could be read for conversions *other than* `%c`, `%s` or scansets (because the leading white space is not part of the conversion for *these*.
- `0` if the first character read does not match the scan set or the first character after white space does not match the format of the scalar conversions.
- otherwise it returns at least `1`.